# How to customize root in android google map navigation?

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation

I am implementing Google navigation by opening the URL -

https://maps.google.co.in/maps?saddr=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&daddr=xxxxxxxxxxxxx

where xxxx means source address and destination address.

It will show the options for different routes or show the default route.

I have to set a new route from option at first and after that instead of default route, i want to show the route i selected first in my app...

please help me ..
thanks in advance

Comment: I'm guessing that you mean 'route' not 'root'. It so, you might like to correct the spelling.

Comment: yes . i meant route..thanks